# jq filtering on specific key and collating values into single csv cell

Tags: json, csv, jq

Given this json:

```
{"data": [
  {
    "account_id": "123",
    "account_status": "active",
    "name": "john doe",
    "email": "johndoe@anywhere.com",
    "product_access": []
  },
  {
    "account_id": "345",
    "account_status": "active",
    "name": "jane doe",
    "email": "janedoe@anywhere.com",
    "last_active": "2023-08-23T13:03:27.811473590Z",
    "product_access": [
      {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "key": "product1",
        "url": "acme1.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "key": "product1",
        "url": "acme2.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "key": "product1",
        "url": "acme3.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Product 2",
        "key": "product2",
        "url": "acme4.com",
        "last_active": "2023-08-23T13:03:27.811473590Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Product 3",
        "key": "product3",
        "url": "acme5.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "key": "product1",
        "url": "acme4.com",
        "last_active": "2023-08-17T18:21:52.472085713Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I am trying to write a jq expression such that the output is the following in a csv file (not adding escape characters here for simplicity):

```
"account_id", "account_status", "name", "email", "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3"
"123", "active", "john doe", "johndoe@anywhere.com", ",,"
"345", "active", "jane doe", "janedoe@anywhere.com", "acme1.com, acme2.com, acme3.com, acme4.com", "acme4.com", "acme5.com"
```

I've tried this so far...

```
jq -r '["account_id", "account_status", "name", "email", "product 1", "product 2", "product 3"],
        (.data[] | [.account_id, .account_status, .name, .email,
                    (.product_access[] | select(.key == "product1").url // ""),
                    (.product_access[] | select(.key == "product2").url // ""),
                    (.product_access[] | select(.key == "product3").url // "")] | join(",")) | @csv'
```

It doesn't collate the Product n urls into the single cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
jq -r '
["account_id", "account_status", "name", "email", "product 1", "product 2", "product 3"],
(.data[]
 | [.account_id, .account_status, .name, .email,
    ("product1","product2","product3") as $prod
    | [(.product_access[] | select(.key == $prod).url)] | join(",")
   ]
)
| @csv' input.json
```

Comment: FYI, [jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/v7L-diz2058) for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to apply the `join` to the products, not all the columns. You need to apply it to each product separately.

```
jq -r '
["account_id", "account_status", "name", "email", "product 1", "product 2", "product 3"],
(.data[]
    | [.account_id, .account_status, .name, .email,
      ([.product_access[] | select(.key == "product1").url] | join(",")),
      ([.product_access[] | select(.key == "product2").url] | join(",")),
      ([.product_access[] | select(.key == "product3").url] | join(","))
     ] ) | @csv'
```

Comment: Thank you choroba!  That makes sense...however I'm seeing this as output from that filter: ```"\"account_id\",\"account_status\",\"name\",\"email\",\"product 1\",\"product 2\",\"product 3\""
"\"123\",\"active\",\"john doe\",\"johndoe@anywhere.com\",\"\""
"\"345\",\"active\",\"jane doe\",\"janedoe@anywhere.com\",\"acme1.com,acme2.com,acme3.com,,,acme4.com,,,,acme4.com,,,,,,,acme5.com,\""```